# Connect components without signals

Tags: vhdl

Is there a way to connect vhdl component directly without defining signal?

Just for a case where 2 blocks are connected without any other use for the outputs of the first block?

Comment: Sure.  Forget about ports.  Declare a signal in a package.  Both designs reference the package and can use the signals there.  Or course, your synthesis tool probably will not like this, but for testbenches it is ok

Answer (score 1):

You do need to declare signals to connect component instantiations. Sigasi can do this automatically for you : [demo](http://www.sigasi.com/screencast/declare-vhdl-signal-or-variable).

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done (currently - there is thought for a future revision which may allow "inferred connections").

Tools like Emacs' VHDL-mode and Sigasi can make this much easier though, but generating the boilerplate code for you.

Answer (score 0):

When using (x)emacs with the [VHDL mode](http://www.iis.ee.ethz.ch/~zimmi/emacs/vhdl-mode.html):

1) Put the cursor in a VHDL entity

2) M-X vhdl-port-copy

to generate the signals

3) M-X vhdl-port-paste-signals

note: vhdl-port-paste-[component|entity|constants|instance|...]

Comment: At least in my version of VHDL-mode (3.33.28) it's `vhdl-port-copy`.